# Does Chrome deprioritize Javascript execution extensions?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I have been developing a simple browser extension, and I have ran into a very strange behavior that happens on Chrome while it doesn't happen on Firefox. Basically, the extension runs much slower in Chrome than in Firefox, and it takes 3+ seconds to add a single class to a button, while it happens in milliseconds in Firefox.

[This repo](https://github.com/karakanb/chrome-extension-slow-test) contains a demonstration of the issue. What is supposed to happen is, when the input box is not empty, the button should change color, this is almost instantaneous in Firefox, but it takes seconds to update in Chrome.

I have noticed that:

Further observations:

- The problem goes away if I remove the TailwindCSS import in `App.vue` file.
- The problem goes away if I remove the background script from the `manifest.json` file.
- The problem goes away if I run performance profiling in Chrome `Performance` tab on the inspect window.
- If I visit the extension page directly in the browser, like `chrome-extension://extension-id/popup/popup.html#/` it is totally fine, there is no lag or anything.

For the first two, Webpack seems to be including a lot of extra code into the bundle, and removing any of these seems to be reduce the bundle size significantly.

For the third one, I imagine Chrome is prioritizing the extension execution when the performance profiling is enabled, therefore it is fast back again. This is probably the case for the last one as well because the page is in focus and it is probably the most important page to run for Chrome at that point. I believe this problem has something to do with the way Chrome runs Javascript in extensions or the way it redraws the UI.

This seems to be a very weird behavior, and I couldn't find any prior reports regarding this behavior. Any help is appreciated, I cannot think of anything else to add but I can add more details as requested.

Comment: No, this is not normal behavior for extension code. It's a bug. If you're on MacOS with an external display then it's probably https://crbug.com/971701 otherwise you can report a new one.

Comment: Oh, I haven't thought about the external screen, but this seems to be the case. I am Macbook Pro with an external screen, and the extension works totally fine on the main Macbook screen. Thank you so much, I'll share the details under the bug report.